# chrome.scripting.executeScript pass parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in the `popup.js` file on my Chrome Extension:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  function: myFunc,
});


function myFunc() {
  // do something
}
```

However, I would like to pass a parameter from the `executeScript` to `myFunc`. Something like this:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  argument: {"arg1", "arg2"}
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  function: connectCmd,
});


function myFunc(arg1: string, arg2: string) {
  // do something
}
```

or something equivalent. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/) the `args` (array of arguments) property is available since Chrome 92.

- These arguments must be JSON-serializable i.e. string, number, boolean, null, array/object that consists of the mentioned types. In short the injected code will see the same thing as you can see by running `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(args))` meaning that you can't transfer classes, Set, Map, and other nontrivial objects.
- You can use `func` property in Chrome 92+, which is the new preferred alias of `function`.

```js
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  args: ['foo', 'bar']
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  func: myFunc,
});

function myFunc(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(arg1, arg2); // will print `foo bar` in console of the web page
}
```

In the older Chrome you'll have to use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/).