# Passing unserializable into a function and calling it later

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scope

I've been trying to send an un-serializable object called `$$` that was created inside my **chrome extension** popup script into a tab. The problem is, the function I am using is `chrome.scripting.executeScript` which takes an object as input with these two values: `target` and `function`.

Here is an idea of what I have:
**popup.js**

```js
const $$ = {"blah":"test"}; // This value is supposed to be unserializeable

// tab is declared somehwere else, not important now
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    function: step1,
});

function step1() {
    console.log($$);
    // Throws $$ is not defined error because it's not in scope?

}
```

I don't know how to pass in $$ into step1 without calling it immediately (`step1($$)`)

If I use the `args` parameter along side `target` and `function`, it only lets me pass *serializeable* data.

Comment: As you can see in the documentation the `args` parameter is available since Chrome 92.

Comment: So I could pass in target, function, and args? Then refer it with "this.args" or "args"?

Comment: [chrome.scripting.executeScript pass parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640372)